# Dual seat in Linux with 3d acceleration and one video card

Tags: linux, multi-monitor

Is there any way to set up a dual seats (i.e. two keyboards, mice, screens) with 3d acceleration but only one video card, in particular an AMD APU? They seem to support multiple monitors, so it doesn't seem to be a hardware issue, it's just a matter of getting Linux to associate different sessions with them.

Comment: Do you have evidence, that any "normal" multi seat setup does not have 3d acceleration for both seats?